# Using Mouseover to change the appearance of a button without writing the button specification twice

Tags: dynamic, button

When I code in *Mathematica*, I often find myself having to repeat large chunks of code for a function to work. The latest example of this is a color changing button that prints when clicked, code shown below.

```
Mouseover[
 Style[
  Button[
   Pane["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
    ImageSize -> {34, 24}],
   Print["Print"],
   Appearance -> None
   ], Background -> Red
  ],
 Style[
  Button[
   Pane["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
    ImageSize -> {34, 24}],
   Print["Print"],
   Appearance -> None
   ], Background -> Green
  ]
 ]
```

The only thing that is changing on the mouse over is the button color, but for this to work I need to repeat a whole chunk of code.

A simpler way of doing this is to define a button color function, and then use that in the Mouseover function, code shown below.

```
ButtonColor[color_] :=
 Style[
  Button[
   Pane["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
    ImageSize -> {34, 24}],
   Print["Print"],
   Appearance -> None
   ], Background -> color
  ]

Mouseover[
 ButtonColor[Red],
 ButtonColor[Green]
 ]
```

This is better, but what if i only have to refer to the button color changing function for one mouse over button? Should I really have to define a function to use it for one instance?

I think the ideal way to code this would be to use Table or something similar, code shown below.

```
Mouseover[
 Table[
  Style[
   Button[
    Pane["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
     ImageSize -> {34, 24}],
    Print["Print"],
    Appearance -> None
    ], Background -> color
   ],
  {color, {Red, Green}}
  ]
 ]
```

The only problem, Table doesn't work because it creates EXTRA BRACES!

Is there a better way of coding this color changing button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have repeat yourself. You can map a pure function defining the button over a list of the background colors and then apply `Mouseover` Like so:

```
Mouseover @@ 
  (Button[Panel["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
     Background -> #], Print["Print"], Appearance -> None] & /@ {Red, Green})
```

[image: button]

Comment: Oohh, this is exactly what I was after, I think. Thanks for the quick reply ^_^

Answer (score 9):

An alternative approach using `CurrentValue["MouseOver"]`:

```
Button[Panel["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
             Background -> Dynamic@If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Green, Red]], 
       Print["Print"], Appearance -> None]
```

or, without the `Panel`,

```
Button["Print", Print["Print"], 
       Background -> Dynamic@If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Green, Red]]
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: Best answer so far, IMO. +1

Answer (score 7):

Another method which doesn't really use `Mouseover` but the `EventHandler`:

```
DynamicModule[{col = Red},
              EventHandler[
                           Button[
                                  Panel["Print", FrameMargins -> {{4, 4}, {4, 4}}, 
                                                 Background   -> Dynamic[col]], 
                                  Print["Print"],
                                  Appearance -> None],
                           "MouseEntered" :> (col = Green),
                           "MouseExited"  :> (col = Red  )
                          ]
             ]
```

The `Button` isn't repeated in the output too, so might make the result a little slimmer.